# Calculating data transfer rate

Tags: disk, data-transfer

Iv been given a question regarding data transfer rates and i am unsure of how to calculate to get the answer. If someone could explain the formula to be that would be great.

A disk with 2 double-sided platters rotates at 6000 rpm, has two hundred sectors per track,
and 500 bytes per sectors. The data transfer rate is: ___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

number of platters x (bytes x sectors)/(60/RPM) =

This is the formula.